# Intl.DateTimeFormat could not parse valid time value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

In my react app, I tried to format a date string within a `<p>...</p>` tag like below:

```js
<p>
    {new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "2-digit"
    }).format(string)}
</p>
```

An example of `string` is `"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"`. This generated `RangeError: Invalid time value`. However, by converting `String` into `Date`, the code below worked.

```js
<p>
    {new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "2-digit"
    }).format(new Date(string))}
</p>
```

Shouldn't `Intl.DateTimeFormat` be able to parse `String` correctly?

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/1396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't Intl.DateTimeFormat be able to parse String correctly?

No. [*DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) objects don't have a parser. The [*format* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) expects the argument to be a Date object (though any value where `ToNumber(value)` is not NaN "works"), not a string (see [ECMA-402](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-intl.datetimeformat.prototype.format)).